# Error when trying to secure mariaDB connection on Ubuntu server using self-signed certificates

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssl, mariadb, self-signed

I am trying to connect to mariaDB server using self signed ssl certificates. What I did so far:

CA:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem
```

Server:

```
 openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 365000 -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
 openssl x509 -req -days 365000 -set_serial 01 -in server-req.pem -out server-cert.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem
```

Client:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 365000 -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 365000 -set_serial 01 -in client-req.pem -out client-cert.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem
```

(everything generated in /etc/mysql/ssl and chown mysql: server-key.pem)

After that, i changed my config files (/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf and 50-client.cnf):

50-client.cnf added lines:

```
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem
```

50-server.cnf added lines:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
ssl = true
```

Everything seemed to work fine, but as soon as I change the 50-client.cnf and try to connect to the mariaDB server I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.
```

Anyone got an idea what I could do to make it work?

Comment: I happen to do the same yesterday. I followed the tips given [here](https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-mariadb-self-signed-ssl-tls-on-ubuntu/) and had succes. (I am too lazy to find the difference between what you did and what is described there )

Comment: I tried your suggested tutorial, but ended up with the same result :(

Comment: It has to do with the `ssl-` in 50-client.cnf. I did not have them and it worked. When I add those I am getting "ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Server certificate validation failed. The signature of the certificate cannot be verified. Error 0x80096004(TRUST_E_CERT_SIGNATURE)".   More info here: https://serverfault.com/questions/399487/cant-connect-to-mysql-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate, which says that the CN for `ca-cert` should be different from `server-cert`.